# Blocking multithreaded TCP Server NullPointerException debugging

Tags: java, android, debugging, exception, tcp

I have a TCP server that accepts data and saves it to a text file. It then uses that text file to create an image and sends it back to the client. Every couple of hours I will get a `NullPointerException` that gets thrown to every client that connects after that. I am not sure how to go about debugging this as I cannot replicate it on my own.

Does anyone have any debugging practices to help me figure out why this is becoming a problem?

The server running is running Ubuntu 12.04 i386 with 2 gigs of RAM. My initial suspicion is that something is not getting closed properly and creating issues but everything should be getting closed as far as I can tell.

```
    ServerSocket echoServer = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    try {
        echoServer = new ServerSocket(xxx);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    while(true)
    {
            InputStream is = null;
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
            int bufferSize = 0;
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            BufferedInputStream bis = null;
            BufferedOutputStream out = null;
        try {

            //Receieve text file
            is = null;
            fos = null;
            bos = null;
            bufferSize = 0;
            String uid = createUid();

            try {
                clientSocket = echoServer.accept();
                clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
                clientSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
                System.out.println("Client accepted from: " + clientSocket.getInetAddress());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Can't accept client connection. ");
            }

            try {
                is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                bufferSize = clientSocket.getReceiveBufferSize();
                System.out.println("Buffer size: " + bufferSize);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Can't get socket input stream. ");
            }

            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream("/my/diretory/" + uid + ".txt");
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("File not found. ");
            }

            byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];

            int count;

            while ((count = is.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                bos.write(bytes, 0, count);
                System.out.println("Receiving... " + count);
            }

            System.out.println("Done receiving text file");
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
            fos.close();

            //image
            String[] command = new String[3];
            command[0] = "python";
            command[1] = "imagecreationfile.py";
            command[2] = uid;
            System.out.println("Starting python script");   
            Boolean success = startScript(command);
            if(success)
            {
                System.out.println("Script completed successfully");
                //Send image here
                String image = "/my/directory/" + uid + ".png";
                File imageFile = new File(image);
                long length = imageFile.length();
                if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                    System.out.println("File is too large.");
                }

                bytes = new byte[(int) length];
                fis = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                out = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                count = 0;
                while ((count = bis.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                    out.write(bytes, 0, count);
                    System.out.println("Writing... " + count);
                }

                out.flush();
                out.close();
                fis.close();
                bis.close();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Script failed");
            }


            System.out.println("Closing connection");
            is.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e); //This is where the exception is being caught

        }

        if(!clientSocket.isClosed())
        {
            try {
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
        if(is != null)
            is.close();

        if(fos != null)
            fos.close();

        if(bos != null)
            bos.close();

        if(fis != null)
            fis.close();

        if(bis != null)
            bis.close();

        if(out != null)
            out.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Post the stack trace, and identify which source line is throwing the exception. Without that it's just a guessing game.

Comment: The answer is the same in both cases. Get the stack trace. You can't do anything without it, and once you have it the solution will be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe exception was thrown in one of your try-catch scope.
And the next try-catch scope found null variables.

for example

```
//Receieve text file
        is = null;
        fos = null;
        bos = null;
        bufferSize = 0;
        String uid = createUid();

        try {
            clientSocket = echoServer.accept();
            clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
            clientSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
            System.out.println("Client accepted from: " + clientSocket.getInetAddress());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Can't accept client connection. ");
        }

        try {
            is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            bufferSize = clientSocket.getReceiveBufferSize();
            System.out.println("Buffer size: " + bufferSize);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Can't get socket input stream. ");
        }
```

if IOException was thrown in "clientSocket = echoServer.accept();" , it will print "Can't accept client connection. ".
When, "is = clientSocket.getInputStream();" executed, it will throw NullPointer because "clientSocket" was not initialized properly.
My suggestion, dont break a sequenced statement in different try-catch scope until it necessary.